# Why are my properties not being set as expected?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a little WPF Apllication where I track some Items. There are a total of 30+ Items, that can be tracked, but none of them have to. This is reflected in a List I populate in the settings section (the TrackedItems object below).

There is a total of 10 Stackpanels I use to display the items. I've made a Collection for them for easier access (StackedpanelsForTrackedItems)

The User has the Option to reduce the panels that are displayed to 3, 5 or 10 (Preferences.NumberNodesDisplayed contains that number) to reduce clutter. So regardless of how many items are tracked, there should never be more SPs visible than this option allows.

Also the application should recognize if the amount of items, that are currently tracked is fewer than the currently selected option.

For example, if i currently only track 6 items, but option is set to 10, it should only display the first 6 SPs regardless.

I came up with this logic:

```
Collection<UIElement> StackpanelsForTrackedItems = new Collection<UIElement>();
foreach (UIElement element in StackpanelItemParent.Children)
{
    if (element is StackPanel)
    {
         StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)element;
         StackpanelsForTrackedItems.Add(sp);
    }
}
int i = 0;
foreach (UIElement item in StackpanelsForTrackedItems)
{ 
        if ((i < TrackedItems.Count) && (i < Preferences.NumberNodesDisplayed))
            item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            item.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        i++;
}
```

Now if i select lets say 6 Items (which means TrackedItems.Count = 6) and I choose 10 Items to be displayed at maximum (which means Preferences.NumberNodesDisplayed = 10) it should still set the visibility of
StackpanelsForTrackedItems[6] to StackpanelsForTrackedItems[9] at 'collapsed', but it doesnt, it always displays every 10 SPs.

How can the if-statement be true if (i < TrackedItems.Count) is already false?

I think I have a major flaw in my logic, but I cant for my life find it.

Help please :)

Edit: as requested

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackpanelItemParent" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackpanelItem1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        // stuff here...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackpanelItem2" Orientation="Horizontal">
        //stuff here...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackpanelItem3" Orientation="Horizontal">
        // stuff here...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackpanelItem4" Orientation="Horizontal">
        // stuff here...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackpanelItem5" Orientation="Horizontal">
        // stuff here...
    </StackPanel>
    //
    //
    //
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackpanelItem10" Orientation="Horizontal">
        // stuff here...
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The Collection gets populated correctly when i debug

StackpanelsForTrackedItems[0] would be StackpanelItem1

StackpanelsForTrackedItems[1] would be StackpanelItem2

StackpanelsForTrackedItems[2] would be StackpanelItem3 etc.

I see no error there :-/

EDIT2: 
I found the error,and  I'm just too dumb I guess

when I ran the app without breakpoints and changed the items to track, this behaviour above occured

so i went ahead an set breakpoints to track down all variables, this however prevented my app to execute the method, where the TrackedItems object gets populated again...

a simple TrackedItems.Clear() fixed everything, obviously once the method is called again later, there would be 12 items in that list and not 6 anymore

i feel really embarrased for asking the question now :(
at least I managed to track it down on my own, and I learned a thing or two from the comments, so it wasnt completely wasted I guess

thanks everybody for trying to help though, much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but you can't modify the collection in a foreach loop. Try with a for loop.

Comment: @Sami You can't modify the collection that is being currently iterated, by that I mean `.Add()` or `.Remove()` which corrupts the Enumerator. However, you are free to alter the object internal state.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I seem to remember that foreach doesn't guarantee to iterate on a collection in order, so the items you're setting to "visible" might NOT be the first "x" ones. Don't know if that is the problem though. Other than that tho, it should work. Can we see the XAML/Code that creates the StackpanelItemParent?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 True. Thanks. Suspected that after commenting.

Comment: @Master_T the foreach will be iterated in the way that the children is being added, which means it will be iterated the same way it is declared in the xaml from top to bottom. However, if the container is a grid and the children arn't sorted by grid.row/column, you might have a different visual and logical ordering.

Comment: But it shouldn't matter here, as a Collapsed item doesn't take any space.

Comment: i added the xaml...however since i didnt specifically iterated through the indexes, would that even matter? as i see he would loop directly through every index and if they were in wrong order, there should still only 6 be displayed, regardless?

Comment: I found the issue and fixed it, see EDIT2...duh :(

Comment: @DanielZschocke whatever you're doing, delete all that and use proper XAML and databinding. Creating or manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have simulated the logic into a list of Booleans. True means to be shown while false means hidden.

The following the user has selected 10 items to be tracked but six only exist:

```
var StackpanelsForTrackedItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                           .Select (e => true)
                                           .ToList();
int tracked = 6;
int max = 10;

StackpanelsForTrackedItems.Select ((sp, index) => sp = (index < max) && (index < tracked));
```

Result:

[image]

For

```
int tracked = 6;
int max = 3;
```

Result

[image]

---

For the WPF visibility change

```
 .Select ((sp, index) => sp.Visibility = 
                            ((index < max) && (index < tracked)) ? Visibility.Visible
                                                                 : Visibility.Collapsed);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've learned a thing here approachwise, although I couldnt use it that way without some adjustments (cant convert boolean to UIElement-error)...i got the idea though....However, I fixed my issue...see EDIT2.

Comment: @DanielZschocke The example was an simile for the real operation, replace `List<bool>` with `List<UIElement>` instead.